# ActiveJob uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-activejob

I have a weird problem with `ActiveJob`.

From a controller I'm executing the following sentence:

```
ExportJob.set(wait: 5.seconds).perform([A series of parameters, basically strings and integers])
```

ExportJob.rb

```
require_relative 'blablabla/resource_manager'

class ExportJob < ActiveJob::Base
   def perform
       ResourceManager.export_process([A series of parameters, basically strings and integers])
   end
end
```

When the controller/action is executed for the first time the process goes fine, but the second time an error is thrown:

```
uninitialized constant ExportJob::ResourceManager
```

The weird thing is that this is not the only job I have in my project, the other ones are being executed without any problem.

I'm Attaching some information of my project:

development/production.rb

```
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :delayed_job
```

Gemfile:

```
gem 'delayed_job'

gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
```

Any clue would be a help for me.

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: Try `::ResourceManager.export_process( ... )`

Comment: use `::ResourceManager`

Comment: or use require_dependency instead of require_relative

Comment: Hi, I'm going to try that. Thank you!

Comment: @dsounded I'm going to try that too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constants don't have global scope in Ruby. Constants can be visible from any scope, but you must specify where the constant is to be found.

Without `::` Ruby looks for the `ResourceManager` constant in lexical scope of the currently executing code (which is `ExportJob` class, so it looks for `ExportJob::ResourceManager`).

The following should work (assuming that `ResourceManager` is defined as a top level constant (eg not nested under any module/class):

```
class ExportJob < ActiveJob::Base
  def perform
    ::ResourceManager.export_process(*args)
  end
end
```

Comment: ResourceManager is not a constant, but a class.  Anyway, I'm going to try your suggestion.

Comment: @EleazarEnrique class' name **is a** constant :)

Comment: @EleazarEnrique no probs, let me know, if that worked for you

Comment: In development environment didn't work, but in production it worked like charm.. I don't understand!!

Comment: I think restating the server/reloading the console will do the job. After all production is what matters (kidding). Don't forget to consider accepting the answer if/when it starts working in dev mode (and ir should) as well

Comment: The error persists, but your help deserves an up vote.  Thank you!

Comment: @EleazarEnrique is it still there in dev mode?